# Form Recognizer compose feature limit: documentation says 100 but response error just 5

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

On Microsoft documentation says ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool?tabs=v2-1#compose-trained-models)):

> With Model Compose, you can compose up to 100 models to a single model
> ID. When you call Analyze with this composed model ID, Form Recognizer
> will first classify the form you submitted, matching it to the best
> matching model, and then return results for that model. This is useful
> when incoming forms may belong to one of several templates.

But I'm trying this feature composing 6 models and I'm getting this error from Form Recognizer API

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "1001",
        "message": "Parameter 'ModelIds' models count exceed limit for compose: 5."
    }
}
```

API version: `v2.1-preview.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Form Recognizer Free resource supports 5 models per model compose. Please upgrade to a paid resource which supports up to 100 models within a model compose to compose more than 5 into a model compose.